# How do I get the JSON body in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, dropwizard

Is there a `@RequestBody` equivalent in Jersey?

```
@POST()
@Path("/{itemId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addVote(@PathParam("itemId") Integer itemId, @RequestBody body) {
    voteDAO.create(new Vote(body));
}
```

I want to be able to fetch the POSTed JSON somehow.

Comment: Please be gentle enough to mark an answer to the asked question or update if they don't suit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need any annotation. The only parameter without annotation will be a container for request body:

```
@POST()
@Path("/{itemId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addVote(@PathParam("itemId") Integer itemId, String body) {
    voteDAO.create(new Vote(body));
}
```

or you can get the body already parsed into object:

```
@POST()
@Path("/{itemId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addVote(@PathParam("itemId") Integer itemId, Vote vote) {
    voteDAO.create(vote);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@javax.ws.rs.Consumes(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

should already help you here and just that the rest of the parameters must be marked using annotations for them being different types of params -

```
@POST()
@Path("/{itemId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addVote(@PathParam("itemId") Integer itemId, <DataType> body) {
    voteDAO.create(new Vote(body));
}
```

Answer (score -4):

if you want your json as an Vote object then simple use @RequestBody Vote body in your mathod argument , Spring will automatically convert your Json in Vote Object.

Comment: can you clarify this  a bit?