# "No content to map to Object due to end of input" when Calling a WS REST

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, jersey

Consider the following method:

```
@POST
@Path("/device")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String putDevice(String jsonObject, @Context HttpHeaders headers, Admin admin)
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try
    {
        return updateDevice(mapper.readTree(jsonObject), Utils.extractUserInfo(headers), admin.getServer(), admin.getPort());
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

When I call the WS from Postman, I get the following exception:

> 08-Feb-2019 14:23:44.138 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException
>   The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be
>   mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container 
>   java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2766)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2682)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

It's maybe important to mention that the exception disappears when I remove the parameter `jsonObject` and edit the method like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/device")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response putDevice(@Context HttpHeaders headers, Admin admin)
{
    String output = admin.toString();
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to add the `@RequestBody` anotation : `putDevice(@RequestBody String jsonObject,..` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm not using spring here. Is there an alternative for that annotation?

Comment: Apparently, "The only parameter without annotation will be a container for request body" , see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157949/how-do-i-get-the-json-body-in-jersey . You can't pass several object this way, there is only one request body.

Comment: The link you posted gave me a clue to resolve the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the link posted by Arnaud, I learned that you can only have one parameter without annotation, and that one will be processed as the request body. So I made the necessary changes, and here's how the method looks now:

```
@POST
@Path("/device")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String putDevice(String jsonString, @Context HttpHeaders headers)
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try
    {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    return updateDevice(mapper.readTree(jsonString),
                        Utils.extractUserInfo(headers),
                        jsonObject.getString("server"),
                        jsonObject.getInt("port"));
}
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

I hope it'll help somebody else with the same problem one day.