# Reading the contents of a body of a POST request in java (using REST)

Tags: rest

Suppose I make a POST request using POSTMAN and have a body in json format. I want to read the contents of body and pass it in a method. How to do it ?

I can see that there is @QueryParam, @PathParam, @HeaderParam etc annotation are used to read the parameters. I don't get how to read body.

say body is
`{
"param1":"value1",
"param2":"value2",
"param3":"value3",
 }`

ServerSide java code:

`@POST`

`@Path("/myresource")`

`public Response addParams( String param1, String param2, String param3)`
`{`
 `do somthing.`
`}`

So I wanted this param1,param2,parmam3 values to be read from requestbody. Is it possible ?

Comment: You could create an object representing your JSON structure (search "Data Transfer Object" or "Value Object") and let JEE map the JSON body to an object which you could process like you wanted: ``public Response post(YourObjectDTO yourObjectDto) { String param1 = yourObjectDto.param1; } ``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the JSON body in Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157949/how-do-i-get-the-json-body-in-jersey)

Answer (score 1):

Define a class like:

```java
public class Foo {

    String param1;
    String param2;
    String param3;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```java
@POST
@Path("/myresource")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addParams(Foo params) {

    String param1 = params.getParam1();
    String param2 = params.getParam2();
    String param3 = params.getParam3();

    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, use a `Map<String, String>`:

```java
@POST
@Path("/myresource")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addParams(Map<String, String> params) {

    String param1 = params.get("param1");
    String param2 = params.get("param2");
    String param3 = params.get("param3");

    ...
}
```

---

Just ensure that you have a JSON parser such as Jackson or MOXy configured in your application.

Comment: I completely agree this, however I can't define a class in a circumstances (because I am asked not to make too many changes/objects in production code..) I wonder if you really require a class ? can I not just write "public Response addParams( Object foo) and proceed ?

Comment: @adityazagade Why cannot you create a class? What's wrong? See my update anyways.

Comment: That should do! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which Java framework you use, but you could declare a @RequestBody parameter in your method and "map" it to a POJO that will correspond to the incoming JSON (just like @Smutje said in the comment).

For example, in Spring, we do it like this,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/example",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity postExample(@RequestBody ExamplePOJO examplePOJO) {

 // Do something
}
```

Comment: No, I wasn't using any framework. Just Jersey with java

Comment: Still, it must be something similar ;)

Comment: There was nothing in the documentation. src:- https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2271

Comment: Since you work with Jersey, you can check this, http://appsdeveloperblog.com/jersey-http-post-example/

And since it is for Jersey, it might also be a duplicate, just flagged your question so that they can check it soon.